# How would I go about creating a Django + SvelteKit webapp?

Tags: django, api, svelte, web-development-server, sveltekit

I've already gotten my fair share of Bootstrap and Django but never tried out other frontend frameworks like Angular, React, etc. and finally wanted to try SvelteKit. So I'm really inexperienced and new with this sort of stuff.

Currently I've already set-up my Django project as well as a SvelteKit project by following the tutorial on their website.

My problem is that I'm confused about how to combine Django and SvelteKit now. Do I just run both servers simultaneously on different ports and get the data from Django JSON APIs into my Svelte frontend or is there some kind of approach to this? I thought that maybe there's a way to get my Django app to render the Svelte files from the Svelte server for me. I just feel really lost at the moment so if anyone could help me or has some resources I could read to get more familiar with the topic, since I didn't find a lot online, that'd be great!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use a vanilla svelte app instead of sveltekit, it's probably possible to set up a flow where your Django API will try to route and handle the request, and for anything it doesn't understand it will serve the svelte app instead of a 400 code. From there the svelte app will try to handle the request, and if it doesn't understand, render a 404 page. I haven't seen this done though so you would have to research how on your own. I've only seen this pattern with a .NET and React combo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, understand the difference between Svelte and SvelteKit. [SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/) is a front-end + server solution that is a layer above vanilla [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/). SvelteKit adds things like routing and support for sever(less) functions.

If you want to use Django for all your server-side processing, you should just use (vanilla) Svelte to write independent web components that you call from html served by Django. No need to use SvelteKit if you aren't using any of the extra framework features.

- How to [write a web component with vanilla Svelte](https://blog.logrocket.com/build-web-components-svelte/)
- How to [write a web component with SvelteKit](https://www.colorglare.com/svelte-components-as-web-components-b400d1253504).

If you want to just write your API's in Django and do everything else from SvelteKit, I would run both Django and SvelteKit servers from different subdomains and/or ports. Like `django.example.com` and `kit.example.com` or `example.com:8000` and `example.com:3000`.

SvelteKit also provides a low-level [`handle()`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#handle) hook that can bypass SvelteKit, but usually JS/node.js is still used. I think it would be tricky to pass a request from SvelteKit to Django.

Comment: +1 to this, and it's also worth mentioning that you can get the full SPA experience with a vanilla svelte app including client side routing and many other features, and in some situations serving the front end from a CDN might actually be better for your users. All Sveltekit is doing is formalizing features people commonly use and adding a "batteries included" server layer. (but I still love sveltekit, and I'm still writing 2 side projects with it!)

Comment: Thank you for your help! There are so many options out there and it can become kind of overwhelming at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple template for svelte and django.  please check this link: https://github.com/Pei2tech/svelte4django. What you need to add routing to support svelte instead of using  sveltekit.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32686302)

Answer (score 0):

I find myself having the same question, it's not perfect but I got it to work with the following:

- Create a directory that will contain everything, e.g. *my-project*
- Inside the directory create your Django project, e.g. *django-svelte*, with `django-admin startproject django-svelte`
- From *my-project/django-svelte* create an app to contain the svelte app, e.g. *frontend*, with `python manage.py startapp frontend`
- Inside *frontend* create two subdirectories *templates* and *static*; inside each of them create a *frontend* directory. (You should have *frontend/templates/frontend* and *frontend/static/frontend* in the end)
- Inside *my-project* initialize a svelte-kit project, e.g. *client*, with `npm init svelte client`
- Inside *client* install all packages and add *@sveltejs/adapter-static* with `npm install` and `npm i -D @sveltejs/adapter-static`
- Replace the content of *svelte.config.js* with:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

export default {
    kit: {
        paths: { base: "/static/frontend" }, // Adjust according to where you collect static files and the name of the Django app 
        adapter: adapter({
            pages: '../django-svelte/frontend/templates/frontend', // Adjust according to the name of the Django app
            assets: '../django-svelte/frontend/static/frontend', // Adjust according to the name of the Django app
            fallback: null,
            precompress: false
        }),

        prerender: {
            // This can be false if you're using a fallback (i.e. SPA mode)
            default: true
        }
    }
};
```

This will write your HTML, JS and CSS files inside the *frontend* app.

- Create a build with `npm run build`
- Collect static files in Django with `python manage.py collectstatic`
- Run Django with `python manage.py runserver` or other servers

I'm sure there are simpler ways though :-)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help! Looks really interesting, the way you did it.

Comment: Hi @mur762, I was able to set up and loaded the page but I think the slot is not working as expected. I added a few lines before and after the slot in layout.svelte and those lines are working as expected. but anything under the slot is not working at all. Can you please help me here. The only error message I'm getting is Not Found 404: at / However Django logs show that requests for static assets is 200 (Successfull). On Sveltekit side only layout page is working not even +page.svelte or index.svelte